# ruby PTY spawn method

Tags: ruby, spawn, pty

I used PTY.spawn to open an Excel file using the gem "roo" but it shows only errors

```
INPUT_FILE = 'sample.xls'

begin
    PTY.spawn("Roo::Spreadsheet.open '#{INPUT_FILE}'") do |r_f,w_f,pid|
        r_f.each {|line| puts line}
    end
rescue Errno::EIO  
end
```

but I get the error: "sh: 1: Roo::Spreadsheet.open: not found"

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you trying to exec ruby code directly from terminal, In your case try something like:

```
PTY.spawn("irb") do |irb_out, irb_in, pid|
  irb_in.printf("require 'roo'\n")
  irb_in.printf("Roo::Spreadsheet.open '#{INPUT_FILE}'\n")  

  irb_out.each {|line| puts line}
end
```